# MS SQL update statement using comma delimited values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a SQL Update statement that will read comma separated values in a text box field & update a table (1 column referencing ID) with these comma separated values.

Specifically I have a table of products that I want to create a form that updates the "Inventory" column in that table.

I update my inventory spreadsheet daily and it would be great if I can copy/paste the CSV of inventory for all my products paste into a textbox hit update and have my table actualized.

I'm not sure how to do this as I need to reference each products unique ID and update that ID with the matching value for inventory stock.

Any ideas, examples highly appreciated.

Comment: please explain along with data

Comment: Why not parse the CSV in the form code? Why do you have to do it in SQL?

Comment: what version of sql server are you using? If it's 2016, they have a nice function: STRING_SPLIT https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx

Comment: If you have a well formed csv file, it should be easier to create a procedure that imports that file using `BULK INSERT` into a temporary table and then process the data the way you want.

Comment: If you prefer a more novice approach you could use Excel. Import the data and use a formula to build update/insert statements. Copy and paste these into SQL or you might be able to connect as an external data source (not sure about that last part). If you know how to write some code you could write a little process to handle everything with the click of a button but I assume you don't otherwise you  would probably not be asking this question.

Comment: Thanks for all the input guys. I'm using SQL 2014 :( I have an excel add-on that allows me to this this very easily but for the sake of other non-administrative users that I do not want accessing SQL directly i'm trying to build something relatively simple through the web interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 then you can use string_split as I stated in the comment above

```
select * from string_split('1,2,3,4,5',',')
```

However:

If you are using earlier version of sql server < 2016 then you can create a function that returns a table then from there you can join to the table you need to update:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStringToValues
(
   @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
  WITH E1(N)        AS ( SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
       E2(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b),
       E4(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b),
       E42(N)       AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E2 b),
       cteTally(N)  AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@List,1))) 
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E42),
       cteStart(N1) AS (SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t
                         WHERE (SUBSTRING(@List,t.N,1) = @Delimiter OR t.N = 0))
  SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@List, s.N1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000))
    FROM cteStart s;
go
```

Then use the function like so

```
SELECT * FROM SplitStringToValues('1,2,3,5',',') as t
```

## UPDATE:

To get the next row's value next to the id as you have asked in the comment you could do something like this below. It is using the LEAD function introduced in SQL SERVER 2012:

```
SELECT Id, Value
FROM   (SELECT 
               ROW_NUMBER() over (order by(select 1)) as cnt,
               t.item AS Id, 
               Lead(t.item) 
                 OVER ( 
                   ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) Value 
        FROM   dbo.Splitstringtovalues('10,20,30,40,50,10,20,30,40,50,60,70', ',') 
               t) 
       keyValue 
WHERE  keyValue.value IS NOT NULL 
and cnt % 2 = 1
```

Comment: As split functions go this is not a good way to go about it. You do NOT need to resort to loops for this. There plenty of better options here. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: what loops are you talking about?

Comment: Thank you for this detailed post MacWise I'm going to pull out my SQL for dummies and try to reverse engineer this query to better understand. I'm beginner level TSQL. 

I appreciate the quick response!

Comment: You bet Alex, my pleasure! an upvote on the answer always helps ;-)

Comment: Well in your original post your function was a big nasty while loop. Keep in mind we can see the edit history so playing dumb as an attempt to make my comment look absurd is rather silly.

Comment: You have since changed it and sadly what you here is also not good. This is the DelimitedSplit8K function originally authored by Jeff Moden and modified by the community over the years. Unfortunately you changed the varchar(8000) to varchar(max). If you read the Jeff Moden post this is an absolutely bad idea because the performance is horrible. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: The solution is this answer is almost entirely from [Jeff Moden's work](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) as it originally appeared back in 2011. He made subsequent improvements that were incorporated into that article in 2012.  If you are trying to understand how it works and why it is good, that article is a gold mine of information.

Comment: Hello Everyone,

Using the function posted by MacWise, i'm able to split my , separated values into rows. Which is great but how can I identify that every other value in my string of comma separated values is the key identity?

So in an example where I have:
1,45,2,65,3,52
where the first number (1) is the ID of that row, and the 2nd number (45) is the value I want to enter into the table as the updated value.

And then rinse repeat?

Comment: Alex, I've updated the answer an added a solution to the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 then you can use string_split

```
select * from string_split('1,2,3,4,5',',')
```